# XDocument to XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

How do you convert an XDocument to an XElement?

I found the following by searching, but it's for converting between XDocument and XmlDocument, not XDocument and XElement.

```
public static XElement ToXElement(this XmlElement xmlelement)
{
    return XElement.Load(xmlelement.CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree());
}

public static XmlDocument ToXmlDocument(this XDocument xdoc)
{
    var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.Load(xdoc.CreateReader());
    return xmldoc;
}
```

I couldn't find anything to convert an XDocument to an XElement. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to convert XDocument to XElement?

Comment: Do you just want the root element?  xdoc.Root?

Comment: -1. "this is not helpful" is note very helpful explanation of the problem. (Unless it is self-assessing the quality of the post, but then it should be comment :)). Also check your keyboard - it seem to eaten some characters from "you"...

Comment: Your code example doesn't even perform the conversion you are asking about.  The code converts `XmlElement` to `XElement` and `XDocument` to `XmlDocument`.  What are you *actually* asking?

Comment: There is no link of converting from XmlDocument to XmlElement

Comment: Now you want to convert from `XmlDocument` to `XmlElement`?

Comment: My reason for using XElement is bcoz i need to pass it to an argument.

Comment: There is no link of converting from XmlDocument to XmlElement. I will convert from XDocument to XmlDocument . Then if i can convert from XmlDocument to XmlElement . I can convert from XmlElement to XElement. Its not clean but i require XElement as it is passed as parameter

Comment: Why not just go from `XDocument` directly to `XElement`?

Comment: @Bobson : that is what i want to do.

Comment: Just get the `.Root` element as Pawel and JohnD said.  I added an answer with an explicit code sample, just to be clear about it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

XDocument to XmlDocument:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(xdoc.CreateReader());
```

XmlDocument to XDocument

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc));
```

To get the root element from the XDocument you use `xDoc.Root`

Answer (score 39):

Other people have said it, but here's explicitly a sample to convert XDocument to XElement:

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(...);
 return doc.Root;
```

Comment: @Pawel - Yes, but I felt the need to make it very explicit, with the trivial code sample, since the OP was still looking for an answer.

Comment: Not to forget this acts on the same reference, i.e. if you edit the resultant XElement, the changes are reflected on XDocument doc as well. This may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 8):

Simple conversion from XDocument to XElement

```
XElement cvtXDocumentToXElement(XDocument xDoc)
{
    XElement xmlOut = XElement.Parse(xDoc.ToString());
    return xmlOut;
}
```

Comment: Not to forget this creates a completely new instance of XElement, i.e. changes made to XElement wont be reflected on XDocument. This may or may not be desired.